# NSManagedObjectID vs custom UUID identifier attribute - fetch performance

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsmanagedobjectid

I would really like to avoid using `NSManagedObjectID` as a way to connect my model structs to their CoreData objects. I mean something like this:

Say I have a `Book` entity in CoreData and then I have a model struct like this representing it for my model layer:

```swift
struct BookModel {
    let name: String
    ...

    let objectID: NSManagedObjectID // I need this to refer back to the entry in the database
}
```

I don't like this approach. It makes working with the structs tedious and, for instance, testing is annoying because I always have to generate dummy objectIds or make `BookModel.objectID` optional.

What I would love to have is an `id` property of type `UUID` inside the `Book` entity. This would be so easy to connect to structs and also allows the structs to properly exist without a database:

```swift
struct BookModel {
    let name: String
    ...
    let id: UUID
    ...

    func object() -> Book {
        // Retrieve managed object using a fetch request with a predicate.
    }
}
```

I've noticed that you can actually have `UUID` properties in an entity. However, the performance difference seems to be enormous. I've created an example that tries to fetch individual objects 10000 times.

First, I fetched them using the `context`s `object(with: NSManagedObjectID)`. I hard-coded all the possible objectIds in an array and passed a random one each time.

Then, I used a simple fetch request with a `NSPredicate` that got passed a random UUID.

The difference in execution time is significant:

> With ObjectID: 0.015282376s
>
> With UUID: 1.093346287s

However, the strange thing is that the first method didn't actually produce any SQL queries (I logged them using the launch argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 4`). This would explain the speed but not why it doesn't need to communicate with the database at all.

I researched a bit but can't really figure out what `object(with: NSManagedObjectID)` actually does behind the scenes.

Does this mean, using a "custom" `UUID` property is not a good idea? I would really appreciate any insights on this!

Answer (score 4):

I would not rely on the `NSManagedObjectID` in your code. It makes your code dependent on Apple's database implementation, which may change at any time, and it would not make your app resilient against future changes.

By way of example, you would not be able to use the new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. It does not support `NSManagedObjectID`: see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/creating_a_core_data_model_for_cloudkit

Instead of hardcoding `NSManagedObjectID` you are better off giving your entities unique UUIDs, as you have suggested. This may or may not affect performance, but you are better off in the long run, as the underlying core database technologies will shift.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did not know this. I always thought `NSManagedObjectID` was one of the fundamental things about Core Data.

Comment: Regarding NSPersistentCloudKitContainer it would just mean that you'd have to serialize your NSManagedObjectID before storing them I think

Answer (score 1):

You should just use a String to represent the NSManagedObjectID. To convert from NSManagedObjectID to string is easy:

```
objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
```

To convert from String to NSManagedObjectID is slightly more complicated:

```
if let url = URL(string: viewModel.id),
   let objectID = context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: url)
```

This will make your model objects cleaner.

NSManagedObjectID is good to be used within one application on one device, but it should never be stored and referenced across different applications on different device. I think it is not true that NSManagedObjectID is not supported for CloudKit.

As per why `object(with: NSManagedObjectID)` is fast. The document says it returns:

> The identified object, if its known to the context; otherwise, a fault
> with its objectID property set to objectID.

This means that if the object has been loaded before, it will return it immediately, if it has not been loaded before, it will return a fault. If you want to trigger a SQL to happen for a good comparison, you need to access one of the attributes after you call `object(with: NSManagedObjectID)`. I would assume the performance should be very similar to the one using UUID.

Comment: I think object ids are maintained between devices: "A managed object ID uniquely identifies the same managed object both between managed object contexts in a single application, and in multiple applications (as in distributed systems). "

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid